# Solving a simple O.D.E using perturbation theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

As a part of an H.W assignment, I'm requested to solve the following O.D.E using perturbation theory and compare to the analytical solution

$$\dot{y}=y+\epsilon$$

where the solution of this equation is given by

$$y(t)=Ae^t-\epsilon$$

Using perturbation theory I assume that

$$ y(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}y_i(t)\epsilon^i$$
 by plugging in I obtain only term up to order of $O(\epsilon)$

$$\dot{y}_0+\epsilon \dot{y}_1 =y_0+\epsilon(y_1+1)$$

therefore
$$y_0(t)=Ae^t$$
$$y_1(t)=Ae^t-1$$

By plugging into $y(t)$ we obtain

$$y(t)=Ae^t+\epsilon(Ae^t-1+1)$$

and therefore the solution I get is

$$y(t)=Ae^t(1+\epsilon)$$

Can anyone point out why the solution in both cases is different, I've done this many times and can't figure out if this is a mistake using the perturbation method or something which is part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get $y_0(t)=A_0e^t$ and $y_1(t)=A_1e^t-1$. If you combine the solutions, you get
$$
y(t)=y_0(t)+ϵy_1(t)=(A_0+ϵA_1)e^t-ϵ
$$
The combination of the constants is just a new constant, so that this solution is already the exact solution.